# how to create signup and login using aptana

Tags: aptana

i am using aptana to code a website to teach myself.
how can i create a server side signup and login?
and how to put it in aptana?

this is the sign up sheet current form

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
 <html>
   <head> 
    <title>Sign-Up</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="signup.css">
    </head>
    
     <body id="body-color">
        <div id="Sign-Up">
          <fieldset style="width:30%">
          <legend>Registration Form</legend>
          <table border="0"> <tr> 
           <form method="post" action="signup.php">          
             <td>Name</td>
           <td> <input type="text" name="name"></td> </tr> 
           <tr> <td>Email</td><td> <input type="text" name="email"></td> </tr>
           <tr> <td>UserName</td><td> <input type="text" name="user"></td> </tr> <tr>
             <td>Password</td><td> <input type="password" name="pass"></td> </tr>
              <tr> <td>Confirm Password </td><td><input type="password" name="cpass"></td> </tr>
               <tr> <td><input id="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign-Up"></td>
                 </tr>
                 
      </table>
            </fieldset> 
     </div> 
       </body> 
     </html>
```

thanks to everyone who helps!

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
 <html>
   <head> 
    <title>Sign-Up</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="signup.css">
    </head>
    
     <body id="body-color">
        <div id="Sign-Up">
          <fieldset style="width:30%">
          <legend>Registration Form</legend>
          <table border="0"> <tr> 
           <form method="post" action="signup.php">          
             <td>Name</td>
           <td> <input type="text" name="name"></td> </tr> 
           <tr> <td>Email</td><td> <input type="text" name="email"></td> </tr>
           <tr> <td>UserName</td><td> <input type="text" name="user"></td> </tr> <tr>
             <td>Password</td><td> <input type="password" name="pass"></td> </tr>
              <tr> <td>Confirm Password </td><td><input type="password" name="cpass"></td> </tr>
               <tr> <td><input id="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign-Up"></td>
                 </tr>
                 
      </table>
            </fieldset> 
     </div> 
       </body> 
     </html>
```

Comment: If you could provide some explanation to the answer. It will increase its value.